# Windows Phone 7 - Silverlight Checkmark color

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell me how I can change the color of my checkmark for a checkbox in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 development?

I see some references on the web for changing a template but that is more for WPF or SilverLight apps, not WP7.

Right now I have a white background on my stackpanel and my background for my checkboxes are black.  It would be sweet to make the checkmark white.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I should mention that I'm creating these checkboxes in the code behind (via a loop), and I'm using VS 2010 for my phone app development.

**The Answer:**

Thanks to Mick who lead me down the right path.  I had to fiddle with it a little but I used MS Blend to create my own style and then I copied the XAML from there and put that style XAML in the App.xaml in between the  tags.

Then I applied it in my code behind like this:

```
chk.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CheckBoxStyle1"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access this by retemplating the control in Blend.

- Target the check box.
- Right click
- Edit Template
- Edit a Copy
- Drill down to the CheckMark path
- Change it's colour

Comment: @Mick - What if I'm not using blend?  I'm using VS 2010.  Can I import my project into blend?  Also, I'm building my checkboxes problematically in code.

Comment: Use it, it's free. You can reuse the xaml once you see what xaml Blend generates for you though, but it's easier to use Blend initially.

Comment: @Mick - If I create a style and then copy it over to my xaml on my project how can I apply it to the code behind where I'm creating my checkboxes?

Comment: How does this work for you? http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/13115/42706.aspx

Comment: @Mick - That might be the answer I was looking for...  I'll try it out today and let you know!  Thanks for passing that along.

Comment: @Mick - That worked like a charm...  I had to fiddle with it a little but I just put that style in the App.xaml in the <Application.Resources> tag.  Then I applied it in my code behind like this: chk.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CheckBoxStyle1"];